# How to write powerful completion blocks?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to write a method with completion block:

```
//typedef head of block
typedef void (^CommonErrors)(NSError *error);

//method with block
-(void)MethodWithString:(NSString*)string onError:(CommonErrors)ErrorBlock;

//somewhere in code:

[self MethodWithString:(NSString*) onError:^(NSError *error)ErrorBlock];
```

That's all ok, if I double-click on `^(NSError *error)ErrorBlock`,
 then I will have this code: `^(NSError *error){code}`

```
[self MethodWithString:(NSString*) 
               onError:^(NSError *error){
                   code
               }
];
```

But every time, when I use this `CommonErrors`,
I use my template: `onError:(CommonErrors)ErrorBlock`.
My code everywhere will be like this:

```
onError:^(NSError *error){
    ErrorBlock(error)
}
```

Can I do this by defining this template somewhere? Or something similar? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I just reread your question - The block type will never be used in a consumers method signature.  The reason for this is that how would someone else know what parameters to pass without looking at the type?

The behavior you are seeing is by design, the typedef of the block expands into an actual signature.

Apparently this is a code snippets question.

See this http://nearthespeedoflight.com/article/xcode_4_code_snippets

Comment: yeah, i know, but is it possible to write something like template or something else? maybe `#define` or something?

Comment: a define wont change anything.  What exactly is the problem?  You defined a block, you got a block, Im not sure what the issue is except for xcode code completion.

Comment: Im trying to figure out what the problem is, It seems that maybe you dont want to have a block for your error handling, so then dont use blocks, just pass an NSError ** to the called function as normal

Comment: My problem is repeated code. in every function i use my temlpate and want to write it faster. so, can i write my template and input it in Xcode, by mapping a hotkey for it?

Comment: np it took me a bit to figure out what you were asking,